# Entity framework manually deleted tables cant be generated from EF migration

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have created migration and created the database and the tables . For example the tables are

`A B C D E` . Now again I have changed some part of code and ran `update-database` command . Everything went smooth and nice and the tables showed the columns . Now accidentally I manually deleted one two tables `D and E`. Now when I try to run the migration with `update-database` . It runs properly but doesn't create the tables which I deleted manually . I tried to delete the existing migration and re-run `update-database` . It gives the error that apart from the two tables . There already an object existing in 'A  ,B, C ' bla bla name.

Any idea how to get rid of this situation without dropping database and recreate the deleted tables using migration ? Cause i dont want to drop the database as it contains the data in rest of the tables. How to proceed in this situation where I have existing tables in database and accidentally I have manually deleted few tables from SQL server from SSMS .

How to recreate the tables again using migration ?

Oh my entity framework version is 6.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution . Its basically change in strategy how we use migration . The Migration Add-migration only checks the Models and the previous migration timestamp cs files possibly . so until and unless we provide `update-database` command in nuget . it Never actually gets to know which Tables have got deleted manually . So  to the context when we try to perform some migration like alter on the tables . It causes problematic migration since that table doesn't exist on the database but the migration assumes it is already there . So for that there is a manual work . Here are the steps after we have deleted a table manually from the database

1. Check the models existing in entities with correspondence to the database table . If we have found there are some anomaly in the database table which is missing from database but it exists as entity that means. They both are not in sync with each other. So we have to find the model => Table relation for each .
2. If we have created initial migration with all tables then copy the deleted `createTable` code from the migration file .
3. Paste it into the last recently generated migration file. And then generate the script or run the `update-database command` . That would create the deleted database table . However there is no automatic command which would both sync between all entities and the database tables . That's something which we have to track partially manual in migration.

Answer (score 5):

EF Migration history is stored in the table _MigrationHistory. Remove the  table from the Database. Caution: This will erase all the Migration history and you will have to re-create all the tables

Comment: I know it's old, but not in every case you should delete whole table. Remove only migration row u need to reapply, database will think its not applied and it will auto update - you don't even need to manually enter command Update-Database. Keep in mind its safe only if u are working on last applied migration, otherwise data inconsistency might happen.

Answer (score 4):

you can do a simple trick here, remove the specific migration history rows, which affect your deleted tables from

> dbo.__EFMigrationsHistory

then run update-database command,
enjoy

Comment: the best solution as usual got no points.. well done anyway!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the most straightforward solution is to generate SQL script form the migration and run only a part of the script, that creates missing tables.

```
Update-Database -Source MigrationBeforeCreatingTables -Target MigrationAfterCreatingTables -Script
```

Comment: But I manually deleted the tables from database. Not from model. The models remain the same . The migrationAftercreatingTables when I try to generate it doesnt give the tables . hence it doesnt have any migration related stuff . Empty UP and Down methods are generated.

Comment: With `MigrationAfterCreatingTables` I meant the migration, where the tables were originally created. Alternatively you can use `Update-Database -Source 0 -Script` command, that generates SQL scripts for all migrations.

Answer (score 0):

not best but possible way:
1)create a new migration, don't update the base
2)find migration that added tables you need
3)copy up and down parts from that old migration
4)past those things in the new migration file
5)update the database by the new migration