# Recreate the deleted tables in database with Asp.Net MVC Code-First Migration Technique

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I deleted some tables manually in my database. I am trying to recreate this tables but when try to `Update-Database` command it doesnt effect.After I deleted last migrations manually on `_MigrationHistory` table. But againg  nothing changed.

What can I do for recreate deleted tables with Code-First Migration?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity framework manually deleted tables cant be generated from EF migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495560/entity-framework-manually-deleted-tables-cant-be-generated-from-ef-migration)

Comment: you can generate script from database(type of data to script: data only) then delete all tables from database, then 'add-migration renew' database on vs then you can retrieve your data to DB

Comment: Database in production. So I cant remove all tables.

Comment: See the answer from Lukas is Salar's link. You don't need to remove all the tables. Generate the script and use the part(s) that refer to the missing tables.